# Wire LEDs to a car battery

Tags: microcontroller

I've got Quantity : x10 of what's described below and I want to wire them in line for my camera to have clear night vision. Thank you

Lenses Type : Crystal Clear

Case Style : 5mm Round

Forward Voltage : 1.5v - 1.6v

Forward Current : 60mA

Wavelength : 850nm

X10 to 12v car battery..

Comment: Do you want to specify Vbat range? Such as 11.5 to 14.4 worst case or simply 12 to 12.5? Or?

Comment: What exactly is your **question**?

Comment: I think the "How Do I" is implied...

Comment: I might suggest 6S2P with a CC NPNx2 current regulator for 6x1.6V=9.6 V and use a std current limiter method or 6S20P for flash and for example. Large arrays are commonly  made for Iris scanners that work well at 10m detecting minutia with high zoom camera for person recognition

Comment: Just adding to my question, sorry. X10 1.5v LEDs to 12-13.8v standard car battery. How would I wire all ten up.?

Comment: This is tagged as microcontroller. How is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist thank you for your comment, will your suggestion work with all ten bulbs running on a 12v car battery without fail I just don't want to blow anything up? A possible wiring diagram sent the mega or Google drive would be brilliant if you could.

Comment: "Clear night vision" _for what, at what distance_?

Comment: @user91899 No I say 6 in series 2 strings in parallel which is closer to below Vbat min.  If you are restricted to 10 then you have two choices. Buy a boost regulator for LEDs for 10*1.6V =16V for 60 mA or say 17V with 1V drop /60mA = 16 Ohms or  5S2P with 120mA and a Constant current limiter like an LM317 with 1.25V drop from Vadj to Vout over 120mA ~~ 10 Ohms with 1/2W R

Comment: Clear vision to make anyone look like a monochromatic ghost (lol) .  BTW choose <10deg beamwidth and get 50 LEDs they are cheap and vary to the brightness easily, but if you want colour, use 10 to 100W arrays ( cheap white spot with lens or floods without <5000K)

Comment: If you want to be lazy, you put a few in series to make a set, and then add a current limit resistor wastefully dropping enough voltage that the current is determined more by the resistor than by the LED forward voltages.  If you want to be sophisticated, you use constant current drivers, again feeding series strings of several LEDs per output.   A little web searching should find practical examples.

Comment: 850nm is a deep red. Just what do you intend to light up with deep red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Image source: [Gringer on Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum#/media/File:Linear_visible_spectrum.svg).*

At 850 nm and forward voltage of 1.5 to 1.6 V those are infrared LEDs (which you probably know).

- Car battery voltage will vary between 12 V and 14.5 V.
- 10 LEDs in series will require 15 to 16 V at a minimum so this won't work well on the battery voltage range.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQcdvp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A simple solution.*

- With five LEDs in series the forward voltage drop will be 8 V.
- If we suppose the battery is 13 V (mid-range) then R1 and R2 need to drop 13 - 8 = 5 V at 60 mA. From Ohm's law we can calculate \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {5}{0.06} = 83 \ \Omega \$. 82 Ω is the nearest standard value.
- The power dissipated in the resistor is given by \$ P = VI = 5 \times 0.06 = 0.3\ \text W\$ so a 0.5 W resistor would be fine (although it will get very warm).

You should take a voltage measurement of your battery under the conditions that the lamp will be used and recalculate as shown above. The next standard resistor value is 100 Ω but any value in between can be made using series combinations of resistors.

The problem with the above solution is that current will vary somewhat with battery voltage and there will be different light intensity with engine off and engine running.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLIMsq.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. The same arrangement but with constant current regulation provides a more stable current through the LEDs over a range of battery voltages.*

Driving the LEDs from a constant current source such as the LM317 will improve the situation. The LM317 adjusts its output so that its OUT pin is 1.25 V higher than its ADJ (adjust) pin. With 22 Ω for R1 and R2 this will occur at \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {1.25}{22} = 57 \ \text {mA} \$ which should be close enough.

Comment: Note that worst case tolerances on diode string Vf +/-7 % and Vbat =/-4% variation or 11% with car running will affect 60mA by total of 11% or 18% respectively over 82 Ohms voltage drop meaning current variation. Not bad but just FYI